# Excel macro 3D chart

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following data in one sheet:

`x  y   offset`

`1  1   2`

`1  2   2`

`1  3   3`

`1  4   4`

`2  1   5`

`2  2   6`

`2  3   2`

`2  4   2`

`3  1   3`

`3  2   4`

`3  3   5`

`3  4   6`

`4  1   8`

`4  2   7`

`4  3   0`

`4  4   9`
and i want to display the offsets in a 3 dimensional way using an excel macro. In other words, here x and y are the coordinates, offsets are the z values. I just want to get a surface/columns over the xy plane. I searched awhile in the internet, but don't find much useful stuffs. Could you give me any hints?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: What do you mean by "display the offset in a 3 dimensional way"? Do you want to plot a certain excel diagram?

Comment: here x and y are the coordinates, offsets are the z values. I just want to get a surface/columns over the xy plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reformat your data, you will be able to use a regular Excel diagram type (3D columns) to graph the data:

```
    1   2   3   4
1   2   2   3   4
2   5   6   2   2
3   3   4   5   6
4   8   7   0   9
```

[image]

VBA code:

```
Sub graphData()
    Range("D3:H7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Tabelle1'!$D$3:$H$7")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DColumn
End Sub
```

You would have to set your range accordingly.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works. I try to add some labels to the axes using the scripts: .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "X", but it appears to the z axis. Furthermore, could you give some sample scripts on modifying the legend?

Comment: How do you wish to modify the legend? Maybe you should ask another question, where you can specify exactly what you need, because you already accepted an answer here. That way more people are prone to help you.